# Losing self-control during drug rehab

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience

Is there any research or theories which can prove that exercising too much self control can lead to losing one's self-control regardless the work or activity a person engages into? From an [article in The Psychologist](https://thepsychologist.bps.org.uk/volume-25/edition-2/self-control-%E2%80%93-moral-muscle) I understand that self-control is a limited resource.

If there are self-control theories proving this fact, I'm specifically interested if it **holds true for addicts especially when they are in the maintenance stage** where they decide that they want to leave drugs and take a path of sobriety and relapse again if they exercise too much too self-control and losing self-control?

Comment: What is 'too much self control'? Quite frankly I don't understand this question. More importantly, perhaps, is that the post reeks of self help. Mind that we can't answer medical questions and you should seek professional help if you want to help someone to be helped with rehab, also if that someone is yourself.

Comment: no it's not a self help question or seeking professional help ma'am. I read this in a research which stated that when you use too much self-control , you tend to lose the ability to engage in self control, the concept related to ego-depletion and self control theories, and one of the articles on self control also stated that self-control is a limited resource.

Comment: I think this is a good question. Often the advice given to people trying to break an addiction to try to keep focus on one thing at a time. For example, not to try to both quit drinking and also start an exercise program and also change diet to avoid fatty foods. However, I haven't seen evidence supporting these suggestions.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I agree , I don't think so i have come come across any research as of now on control addition and preventing relapse with focus being on teaching proper self control and not exhausting self control.

Comment: This isn't a comment but I dont know where else to ask this (I dont have/need reddit or other sites): I'm having serious problems with self control for an addiction I have and I'm unable to visit therapy (for personal reasons) and today I felt like harming myself. I dont know how I'm going to fix myself and I need some support from someone

Comment: @PvParkour I suggest that you reach out to the concerned helplines operating in your state/ district/ country- for ideal support and help. You can reach out to *TWLOHA* or *Samaritans* they operate worldwide- I sincerely hope you get better.